# how to interrupt a thread

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x

i want to kill a thread "mid run" i have 2 loops one dose some things (lest call it 1) while the other (lets call it 2) listens to a keyboard event and i want 1 to terminate as soon as 2 detects the event

i am sorry that my code is a mess it can probably be ignored there is not to much i was able to do

```
import threading
import keyboard
import time

r = sr.Recognizer()


class Main(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()
        self._stop_event = threading.Event()

    def stop(self):
        self._stop_event.set()

    def stopped(self):
        return self._stop_event.is_set()

    def run(self):
        main()

class Listener(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        listener()

def listener():
    time.sleep(0.3)
    keyboard.wait('alt + s')
    print('stop')
    _main.stop()
    time.sleep(0.3)
    keyboard.wait('alt + s')
    print('start')
    _main.start()

def main():
    _listener.start()
    while 1:
        print('m')
        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    _main = Main()
    _listener = Listener()
    keyboard.wait('alt + s')
    _main.start()
    keyboard.wait('esc')
```

Comment: are you missing a `_listener.start()` in this code sample?

Comment: I want to interrupt _main by running code in _listener